# Python script gives error when running as a ubuntu service

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have set up a service, and when I run it, I get the following error:

```
 ImportError: No module named httplib2
```

I have httplib2 installed with pip and 
my systemd ExecStart command is like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/orionas/Desktop/quickstart.py
```

The same script runs perfect from command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I think you probably have installed httplib2 under your user but systemd uses another user to run the quickstart script.

Answer (score 0):

Under [Service] include a line "User=" The python script will then inherit the permissions and paths of that user AFAIK.

Note: It is probably Not recommended to run a systemd service with userid the same as yours. Potential security risk. Another possible solution would be to run the python script within a [virtualenv] http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ Many people do this and as far as I know it's the recommended practise